# The def code seems to be affecting my code somehow

Tags: function, python-3.x

My code worked fine before I added the 'def menu()' code and 'menu()' code in but now it doesnt seem to work! Any ideas on why not? I just get no return, just '>>>'! FYI: All indentations are correct as they were fine on similar code and worked fine before the 'def' function was introduced into the code.

```
def menu() :
     print("Please enter the number corresponding with the option you would like to pick.")
     print("1. Record Purchase(s)")
     print("2. Retrieve Previous Purchase(s)")
     option=input("> ")

 if option == "1":
      customer_id1=input("Customer ID: ")
      file=open(customer_id1.capitalize()+".txt","a")
      info=input("Please enter all purchases seperated by commas: ")
      file.write(info+"\n")
      file.close()
      print("PURCHASE RECORD SUCCESSFUL")
      import time
      time.sleep(5)
      menu()

 if option == "2":
      customer_id2=input("Customer ID: ")
      file=open(customer_id2+".txt","r")
      print(file.read())
      time.sleep(10)
      menu()

 else:
      print("Sorry, that doesnt seem to be an option, returning to menu.")
      menu()
```

Comment: _"All indentations are correct"_:  That might have been true in your file.  The code as shown here, however, has incorrect indentation.

Answer (score 0):

From your mention of >>> I am assuming you are running this in the python shell. In that case, your issue is that you never actually call menu(). You just define it. If you want to call it you have to put a menu() outside the scope of your function declaration.